# "Haven't you got X ?" or "Don't you have X ?" 

Tags: british-english, negation, auxiliary-verbs

In British English negative questions with the verb *have* (when it's a lexical verb and not an auxiliary) can be formed in two ways. Is there any difference between them?

**Type 1**

- Haven't I got your number?
- Haven't you got her number?
- Hasn't he got your number?
- Haven't we got her number?
- Haven't they got our number?

**Type 2**

- Don't I have your number?
- Don't you have her number?
- Doesn't he have your number?
- Don't we have her number?
- Don't they have our number?

Comment: You can do the same thing in American English. My impression is that Type 1 is slightly preferred in British English and type 2 in American English.

Comment: I think there is a general sense of unease with the word "got" instilled by grammar police when we are young, @PeterShor.

Comment: You are both right, although I'd say Type 1 was rather more than 'slightly' preferred in BrEng.

Comment: Of course there's always a third option (well strictly speaking a reordering of the first): Have I not got your number? / Have you not got her number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At school in the UK in the 70's and 80's, we were always taught that "get" and "got" were very lazy and ugly-sounding verbs to use, and that there was nearly always a better alternative. So people of my generation would probably tend to prefer the "Don't I have" variations, at least in formal speech, even though they're all grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure, but I suppose that the first form is preferred when you have the number as a result of some kind of recent action, and the second may mean that you have it for a long time already. In US, as far as I know, the meaning of the first form is usually virtually the same as of the second one.